# get_category_link() or get_tag_link() return wrong category/tag base in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite

i switch blogs and apply:

```
if (is_archive() && !is_tag()){
    switch_to_blog($myblog_id );
    //get current category id
    $category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
    //get category link of switched blog
    $url_cat = get_category_link($cat_id);
    echo $url_cat;
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

when switching blogs the echo shows opposite category base:

```
http://localhost/es/category/archivo/ //should be categoria
```

or

```
http://localhost/categoria/archiv/ //should be category
```

For `get_category_link()` and `get_tag_link()` i always get the opposite base. Of course i could change the base with `string_replace()` but i wonder, if this is intentional or is my approach wrong? In [make Wordpress core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48786) i found a related post (three years old). regards

Comment: some of your steps are a redundant, it would be more straight forward to do this: `get_category_link(get_query_var( 'cat' ));` instead of using the ID to get the category to then get the ID. Otherwise it's probably that `get_category_link` is using cached data, have you tried flushing it before hand? Or cutting out the middleman and using `get_term_link` directly? You should also follow up on that ticket with your own code to indicate this still happens int he latest WP version, an old core ticket with no replies might even be triaged as stale and closed!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the redundancy. Your suggestion is better. I saved the settings->permalinks for both sites several times and also emtied the cache and it persits. Also get_term_link() bears the same twist. Since i am not a programmer, i restrain myself of following up wordpress core tickets. That’s for the pros to do. My expedient is `string_replace()`

Comment: you should definitely comment on it, just to say you had the same issue testing WP 6.1, lots of people who don't program drop in on Core Trac :) ( PS: You're programming here! )

Comment: Ok, i’ll try. Thanks for your help.